How to automate a login prompt with two inputs using WebdriverIO?
I want to automate the prompt shown in the image attached, but i haven't been able to find a way to fill both fields using WebdriverIO. Tried using alert methods like browser.sendAlertText(), but these don't work.
Prompt:
https://i.sstatic.net/hI7CW.png
I checked this question related to this problem How to fill login prompt with Webdriver IO?, but the solutions given there (Using browser.url(https://<username>:<password>@<url>) or custom browser profiles) are not suitable for the project I'm working on.
Is there other ways to automate this login prompt using WebdriverIO? If so which?
Maybe another solution, not with WebdriverIO itself, but compatible with it?

@Jerónimo There are so many basic login tutorials for not just Wdio but every other automation library. Always google and welcome to the Club!
https://blog.kevinlamping.com/testing-your-login-an-in-depth-webdriverio-tutorial/ this one is from Kevin himself.
